# load / remove multiple models in PhiloGL - WebGL

Tags: webgl, webgl-extensions

I am trying to load & remove models from the main webgl view with philoGL.
In the original script I found the place where one model is loaded. 
However, I want to remove the first model and replace it with a second.

This is how a model is loaded at start:

```js
model = new O3D.Model({
    program: 'default',
    drawType: (item[0] == 't') ? "TRIANGLES" : "TRIANGLE_STRIP",
    vertices: item[1],
    normals: item[2],
    colors: item[3],
    indices: item[4]
});
scene.add(model);
```

I was thinking about running the following code:

```js
scene.remove(model);
scene.add(otherModel);
```

Ideas anyone?
Thanks,
EL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to replace a `model` in philoGL is

```js
var indexModel = scene.models.indexOf(model);

if (indexModel > -1) {
   models.splice(indexModel, 1, otherModel);
   scene.defineBuffers(otherModel);
}
```

This is because you cannot track the position of the `model` that you want to replace with the methods that PhiloGL have. To perform operations in `model` you have to access the `models` property of the `Scene` object directly.

Comment: Thanks. I got this working. One problem persists -> when transformations like camera rotations have been applied, reloading a model will display it at the initial orientation. Can I update the model coordinates somehow?

Comment: It seems that translation / zoom is synchronized but not model specific rotations. I am displaying models of the same object under different conditions. Hence I would like to have a consistent rotation for all models.